# How to test if item in toolBar is FlexibleSpace item?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonsystemitem

I want to know which `UIBarButtonItem` enumerated in `self.toolbarItems` is a button and which is flexible space item.

Comment: There's no public API to access the system style of a bar button item.

Comment: :) why I'm not surprised?

Comment: Check out `_barButtonItemFlags` at `UIBarButtonItem.h` if you are into using private API. Otherwise you can always make limitation of creating the items only from the code, subclass `UIBarButtonItem` and save the value of `UIBarButtonSystemItem` at the public var.

Comment: can you post some example code as answer so I can test if it fits my need? Please be as specific and detailed as possible as I'm noob at objective-c programming:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **A-Live** confirmed my findings that one is not able to query the UIBarButtonItem to check if it is FlexibleSpace (or FixedSpace) I've used tag to mark those items as flexible and fixed space (2 different integers) and put those numbers in the constant then in code I use:

```
for(int i=0; i<self.toolbarItems.count; i++)
{
    if(item.tag != TOOLBAR_FIXED_SPACE_TAG && 
       item.tag != TOOLBAR_FLEXIBLE_SPACE_TAG)
    {
        //count real button:)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above I wasn't able to get to actually work, so I used this. Hopefully this can help someone:

```
 for(int i=0; i<[buttonArray count]; i++){
      UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[self items] objectAtIndex:i];
      if(buttonItem.title){
           NSLog(@"Double Boom %@", buttonItem);
      }
 }
```

** Flexible/Fixed space doesn't contain a title... This is the only real difference I could immediately see. So, I am literally just checking for a title.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty Swift 5.0 solution:

```
let fixedSpaces = toolbarItems?.filter({ $0.description.contains("systemItem=FixedSpace") })
```

It may break over time but will suffice for debug purposes.

*Apply hand sanitizer after each use.*